# Image as background for magazine cover in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, images

I've created a new car guide magazine, similar to [this example](http://content.yudu.com/Library/A1mxqt/AutoExchange190210/resources/index.htm?referrerUrl=http%3A%2F%2Ffree.yudu.com%2Fitem%2Fdetails%2F131632%2FAuto-Exchange-190210).

However, I cannot get the image to fit exactly to the page size, in my case 222 x 291 mm ( width x height) and it ends up looking squashed and stretched when I did 'Fit content to frame'. I can get images to work in InDesign, using the Place command, no issues there, but getting it sized right is the issue.

I have tried Photoshop, and am wondering, is this the solution, resize images in Photoshop before using Place command to insert image into InDesign document?

This is my image I am using for the background: [Image here](http://www.2015carsredesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/2014-toyota-hilux1.jpg).

I have got the text on my page and front cover advert working well (PDF embedded in page), it's just getting the background to work which is the issue.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to scale the image, not alter the proportions. Place the image in InDesign, click on a resize corner, and hold shift to drag and *scale*. Your image of course needs to be big enough from the start; to scale down. If the *format* is not corresponding in proportions, you must either find another image, crop the one you got or use other visual elements to make it a good front page.

Answer (score 1):

`Fit content to frame` is causing the problem. It does as it says; fits the content to the frame which, in your case, would squeeze it horizontally.

What you need to do is `Fill Frame proportionally` or `Fit Content Proportionally`. It will likely cut off some of your image, because of the proportions of your image are different compared to the area you have available.

Answer (score 1):

I see you already found an answer but here are some best practices!  For every piece of content there is also a frame.  First you'll need to adjust the frame and then you can appropriately scale the content, here's how:

With the `direct selection tool` click once to select your image.  With this selection you should see a *blue bounding box* with anchors that allow you to freely transform the frame.  Go ahead and snap the frame into alignment with the page; to easily achieve perfect alignment, make sure you have smart guides turned on by going into the menu `View > Smart Guides`.  If when you do this your content disappears, don't fear!  This just means that your content is not currently in the frame.  With the frame still selected, press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to center the content inside the frame.

Next you will want to double click the content and you should now see a *gold bounding box.* Now, still using the `direct selection tool` grab a corner and <kbd>click</kbd> + <kbd>drag</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd>.  You should witness the content scaling equally in all directions as you move your cursor around. Simply drag outwards until the content's yellow bounding box is outside of or at least abutting the frame.  If the content itself is not the same proportions as the frame, you will essentially be trimming the content by hiding it behind the frame which is why when you chose `Fit Content to Frame` your image was getting distorted.

Now use your artistic vision to arrange the image in a visually pleasing way!  If you only remember one thing, remember that when working in InDesign you are dealing with content and frames.  Understanding the relationship between content and frame will help you achieve InDesign mastery.  Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers work, But if its for a magazine and you are planning on printing it. you should use a DPI of 300. The political correct way to reach this is to see what size you photo needs to be eventually. Then open photoshop new document on the size you need to have your photo and put DPI on 300 (resolution / Points per inch) Then create the document and crop/enlarge it towards it (if your enlarging watch out for pixels!)

Then in indesign when ur placing your photo, do it in a new image frame cause the old one keeps the scaling from your old photo so its easier to create a new one.

Good luck